# Does anyone know of a U.S. city that has crime data with location?

Tags: data.gov, crime

More specifically I want to repeat this study for another city than Chicago: http://blog.uber.com/chicagotaxicrime

The data for Chicago: https://data.cityofchicago.org/Public-Safety/Crimes-2001-to-present/ijzp-q8t2

Edit 1: Although I forgot to mention that I was wondering if there was info on the number of crimes committed in taxi cabs (that was what I meant when I said "location", I should have been more specific).

Comment: i have crime data for many cities in virginia, but few post them like chicago or philly (mentioned below). if you want data for virginia localities i'm more than happy to pass them on.

Comment: I updated my answer below based on your edit.  Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

There are quite a few cities that publish this data. A quick way to find it, is via [Data.gov](http://data.gov), which provides local government as well as federal government data.  There are 53 city crime statistics datasets published, most of which include location data:

- [All 53 city crime datasets](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?organization_type=City%20Government&sort=score%20desc%2C%20name%20asc&q=crime), which are from 9 cities, but broken down by multiple factors for better analysis
- As an example, [Honolulu's crime data](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/crime-incidents) has specific locations

There is also a large set of data about [sexual assaults](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=sexual%20assault&sort=score%20desc%2C%20name%20asc&page=1), particularly but not exclusively on college campuses.

For taxi location crimes, you might consider diving into the [National Crime Victimization Survey](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=sexual%20assault&sort=score%20desc%2C%20name%20asc&page=1) custom tables where you can extract the relationship between the victim and assailant, and the location (although taxi is not explicitly noted).

There are also crimes against taxi drivers, which may be of interest.  Some of that data can be found at the [Taxi Library](http://www.taxi-library.org/safety.htm).

Comment: must of those datasets are of the same ~ six cities, just different years.

Answer (score 7):

The Open Knowledge Foundation keeps a list of Cities that publish crime datasets. Most datasets have location data. In some cases the location is in State Plane coordinates instead of Lat/Lon. They list 51 cities.

http://us-city.census.okfn.org/dataset/crime-stats

Below is a blog posting I posted a year ago on methods for doing crime analysis:

http://www.opengeocode.org/articles/crime%20analysis.txt

Below is a PPT presentation I've given in the Portland, OR area. Starting at slide 31, we show our method and results for doing location based crime analysis in Portland, OR for correlations with public transit stops and alcohol establishments.

http://www.opengeocode.org/articles/Open%20Data.pptx

Answer (score 4):

The City of Philadelphia makes Part 1 Crime Incidents available as a bulk download and via an API (ESRI ArcGIS online):

http://opendataphilly.org/opendata/resource/215/philadelphia-police-part-one-crime-incidents/

The data includes the lat/lon of the crime incident.

Answer (score 0):

NYC and SF release such data over their open data platform. See e.g.: https://datasf.org/opendata/

More interestingly, Portland (Oregon) has recently launched a crime prediction challenge and released crime-related information here:
https://www.nij.gov/funding/Pages/fy16-crime-forecasting-challenge-faqs.aspx