# Crime rate data for American cities

Tags: data-request, usa, legal, crime, police

I'm writing a paper and I'm interested in monthly crime rates in American cities.

The FBI database contains only yearly crime rates and it stops at 2012 (http://www.ucrdatatool.gov/), and each individual police station varies in their degree of reporting. Anyone know of dataset that will satisfy my needs?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a link to the FBI database you mention?

Comment: i've got over a decades worth of data for localities in virginia, some of its monthly...so not big cities, but i've got it if you want it

Comment: @philshem edited to include FBI database.

Comment: @albert I'm looking for monthly UCR data for state of Virginia, I cant find any source for it. Here is a sample study that uses monthly data from Virginia http://papers.tinbergen.nl/03040.pdf

Comment: [this va crime github repo](https://github.com/jalbertbowden/va-crime) is really messy...sorry. UCR comes from VSP so I'm assuming the reporting is same/similar. [VSP releases annual reports here](http://www.vsp.state.va.us/Crime_in_Virginia.shtm) and i've collected, pulled data out for most [in this folder](https://github.com/jalbertbowden/va-crime/tree/master/vsp-crime-in-virginia). I think that is what you want. If you need more/have questions, feel free to reach out: jalbertbowden gmail

Answer (score 2):

This [site](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/content/NACJD/guides/ucr.html#desc_al) goes back several decades. Each file is pretty large but also has the data broken down by month. I don't think you'll be able to get around varying degrees of reporting, that's a common problem statisticians have to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to another [question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4272/does-anyone-know-of-a-u-s-city-that-has-crime-data-with-location/4276#4276), and so I'll post a more detailed and updated answer here that might be useful, too.

There are quite a few cities that publish this data. A quick way to find it, is via [Data.gov](http://data.gov), which provides local government as well as federal government data.  There are 40 city crime statistics datasets published, most of which include location data:

- [All 40 city crime datasets](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?organization_type=City%20Government&sort=score%20desc%2C%20name%20asc&q=crime), which are from 11 cities, but broken down by multiple factors for better analysis
- As an example, [Chicago's crime data](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/crimes-2001-to-present-398a4) includes crimes from 2001 to the present

There is also a large set of data about [sexual assaults](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=sexual%20assault&sort=score%20desc%2C%20name%20asc&page=1), particularly but not exclusively on college campuses.